# running external program in java

Tags: java

If I am running external program(batch file) from java then, What I need to do:

```
if (process.exitValue() == 0) {//means executed successfully ???
```

Can't the return value be something else and batch executed successfully.

Is that the only way to check??

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your wording, but by convention, [`exitValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) returns `0` upon a successful execution. This is, as far as I know, the only way to check.

**EDIT**:

I suppose you could use [`getErrorStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) - I assume it'll be blank if there are no errors in the process...

Answer (score 1):

Pick one from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the [output stream](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) ( or the error stream )  and interpret it

Answer (score 0):

The exit code of the batch process will be defined by that process but generally an exit code of `0` is defined as successful and a non zero value indicates that something went wrong.  In your batch file you can set the return code by calling:

```
EXIT /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

`%ERROR_CODE%` is the number that will be returned as the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, your program can return any status you want. By convention 0 means success.

For example, if you execute a shell script, the return status will be the return status of the last command executed in your script.

Answer (score 0):

In many programs 0 is is success, negative numbers are errors and positive numbers are warnings. Of course this is just a convention and it all depends on what convention was followed. In most programming languages you can define an exit code for a program and that is what is picked up.

In Java System.exit(n)
In C main is defined as int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and the return from main is the return from the program.